# Who found the Ising transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, history, ising-model, critical-phenomena

The famous story is that Ernst Ising studied the 1d classical stat mech model which bears his name, argued it has no phase transition, and guessed that the same would hold in all dimensions. He was wrong of course, but who actually found the phase transition in this model?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The Ising model was invented by the physicist Wilhelm Lenz (1920), who gave it as a problem to his student Ernst Ising. The one-dimensional Ising model was solved by Ising (1925) alone in his 1924 thesis;[2] it has no phase transition. The two-dimensional square-lattice Ising model is much harder and was only given an analytic description much later, by Lars Onsager (1944). It is usually solved by a transfer-matrix method, although there exist different approaches, more related to quantum field theory."

Comment: Hiya Ryan! Ising was right about 1D: he was talking about the classical model, which indeed has no transition. He was wrong about guessing the same applied to 2D, which I think was clarified by Onsager quite a while later. EDIT: Custer beat me to it

Comment: @JonCuster I'm sure people knew there was a transition before Onsager's solution! https://www.apps.stat.vt.edu/leman/VTCourses/ReviewIsing.pdf suggests as early as the 30s, since they had some version of mean field theory, but it doesn't say precisely.

Comment: All you have to show to know there's some transition is that the order is stable to positive temperature. That's much easier than what Onsager did. We can argue it by thinking about the free energy of domain walls, for example.

Comment: It actually may have been Peierls in the 1936 paper who first realized Ising was wrong (from that article I linked)

Comment: Kramer Wannier got the exact 2D critical temperature before Onsager, using of course their famous duality...

Comment: @MengCheng hi Meng! I think Peierls had the right idea about domain walls but seems to have fudged the counting. As far as I found it does seem KW are the first to show a nonzero critical temp rigorously.

Comment: @RyanThorngren If I remember correctly, Peierls's argument in his 1936 paper can be turned into a rigorous proof that the ordered phase is stable to some nonzero temperature, although not quite precise enough to give the precise value of $T_c$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first proof of the existence of a phase transition in (the two-dimensional version of) this model is due to Peierls in [this classical paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/on-isings-model-of-ferromagnetism/C0584C5711BC3D25830B63A4C2F09609) from 1936. The method of proof, today known as *Peierls' argument* has become a cornerstone in the rigorous analysis of phase transitions and been the source of many generalizations of extremely wide applicability.

A few years later, exploiting the self-duality of the nearest-neighbor Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, Kramers and Wannier determined (heuristically) the value of the critical temperature in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.60.252) from 1941. Many ideas introduced in this paper have also led to important generalizations and further insights later on.

Finally, the first computation of the free energy of the planar model (at zero field) was made by Onsager in [his celebrated work](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.65.117) in 1944 and allowed an analysis of the critical properties of the model. The implications of this work triggered the whole modern theory of phase transitions.

---

Concerning the rigor of Peierls' work: in my opinion, all the ideas in the paper are correct and the proof is essentially correct (at the mathematician's level of rigor; of course, it's much more rigorous than many works in theoretical physics). Nevertheless, the first fully rigorous versions of his argument are usually considered to be these papers by [Griffiths](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.136.A437) and [Dobrushin](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=30737&option_lang=eng).

---

Finally, concerning the history of this model and of its impact on modern statistical mechanics, I strongly recommend this series of papers by Niss : [1920-1950](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-004-0088-3), [1950-1965](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-008-0039-5), [1965-1971](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-011-0086-1).

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping you'd come weigh in :)

Comment: My pleasure: this is a topic I enjoy very much ;) .